# what is causing IE8 to render in IE7 mode by default

Tags: internet-explorer-8, document, mode

this site : http://medisra.sideradesign.com
it is rendering in IE7 document mode by default.
Is this due to a CSS or HTML validation error? how can I identify what's causing it?
thanks

Comment: Highly relevant: `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7` is one of the HTTP response headers being served to IE8. The *real* question is, where is that header being set from?

Comment: Just an FYI, after having looked over your previous posts, I notice a couple things that you may think about doing. 1. When/if a suitable answer is given, please mark it as the answer. 2. It seems the majority of your posts are regarding the document compatibility mode. I suggest you do research on document compatibility before asking 4+ questions that are directly related to that topic. The answers are out there. I provide a great reference to help you get familiar with document compatibility in my answer. See below.

Comment: I had a similar problem with IE9 always coming up in IE7 'Document Mode' even though IE9 was the page default.   I had "<!DOCTYPE html>" at the top of my page and no mention of "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />".  IE was in [Compatability Mode](http://superuser.com/questions/350155/internet-explorer-start-internet-explorer-9-in-internet-explorer-7-mode-as-defa/350156#350156). (go to the menu => Tool => Compatability Mode and uncheck. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's all the places I can think of where the header could be coming from.

Considering your comment:

> I have other subdomains on the same
>   server and the sites render in
>   standards mode.

It's unlikely to be defined in Apache's `httpd.conf` or similar.

- Have you made 100% sure there are no other `.htaccess` files or other configuration files which could be introducing it?
- Is your PHP code outputting the header? It would look like this in PHP:
  `header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7');`
- Could it perhaps be the fault of a Wordpress plugin?

You could  use a utility to search in every single file of the website for the string "EmulateIE7".

If you still can't find it after following through those ideas, I'm afraid I can't think of anything else.

Comment: BINGO! I found this in the Thesis theme compatibility.php file : if (preg_match("/MSIE 8.0/", $browser) && !is_admin())
  header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7');

Comment: but I can't just comment it out because if the theme is updated, it will be overridden. I wonder if it's possible to override it

Comment: Haha, I'm glad you finally found it :) I don't know much about Wordpress internals, but a quick Google search [found this](http://hubpages.com/hub/Thesis-Theme-with-Wordpress-MU). It looks like someone else has had the same problem.

Comment: thanks thirtydot! you've been very helpful. I don't like working with the Thesis theme, but it was a client requirement, so...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a good reference about defining document compatibility mode.

This will render all pages on the site in IE7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: the web server is apache. I have other subdomains on the same server and the sites render in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the source of that page if the head contains the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

If it does, that's why it renders the page like IE7 by default.